# Index Error for random library in python. Works for small inputs but doesn't work for large inputs

Tags: python, random, index-error

I have to create a self avoiding lattice path which moves in 4 directions (North, East, West, South).
I have written a function for this:

```
n=int(input())
edges = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -1]]
make_step = lambda point, edge: [x+y for x,y in zip(point, edge)]
path=[[0,0]]
x_coo=[0]
y_coo=[0]
for i in range(n):
    next_points = [make_step(path[-1], edge) for edge in edges]

    allowed_points = [point for point in next_points if point not in path]

    p=rand.choice(allowed_points)

    path.append(p)

    x_coo.append(p[0])

    y_coo.append(p[1])

plt.plot(x_coo,y_coo)
```

It works well until the input is 60 but gives an error when input is greater than 0.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-a4a59bcce6b0> in <module>
     10     allowed_points = [point for point in next_points if point not in path]
     11 
---> 12     p=rand.choice(allowed_points)
     13 
     14     path.append(p)

~\anaconda3\lib\random.py in choice(self, seq)
    259             i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
    260         except ValueError:
--> 261             raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
    262         return seq[i]
    263 

IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Someone please help me resolve this error.

Comment: 'Cannot choose from an empty sequence' means that `allowed_points` is empty. `allowed_points` can be empty if `point not in path` evaluates False for every point in `next_points`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, this is only becuase the pointer encounters a dead end: no matter in which direction it moves, it will step onto the previous path. In this case, the `allowed_points` will be empty.
I modified your code by adding an `if` statement, so it will auto-stop and return the number of steps once it is in a dead end:

```
for i in range(n):
    next_points = [make_step(path[-1], edge) for edge in edges]
    allowed_points = [point for point in next_points if point not in path]
    if allowed_points!=[]:
        p=rand.choice(allowed_points)
        path.append(p)
        x_coo.append(p[0])
        y_coo.append(p[1])
    else:
        print ('dead end, stops when n=',i)
        break
```

In one trail when I set input=100, it returns the following path and stops when n=70:
[image: n=100, stops when n=70]

As you can see the pointer is stuck at (4,12); any one step will overlap with one of the previous paths [(3,12), (5,12), (4,11), (4,13)].

Comment: Is there any way I can get the complete path without stopping in the middle.
Like generating a full path of 200 steps

Comment: The chance of stopping increases with n (because it is a statistical thing).You can test it with some integer input, but I will guess the n will be around 50-80: there is little chance you can reach n=200. To avoid this dead-ending you will need another algorithm (you may need to open a new question!)